# Taking input as paragraph from console

Tags: c++, input

I have been trying for hours and hours to take input from the console as like paragraph. But it's not showing the result in the way it is supposed to when I print it.

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
      string input,line;
      while( getline( cin , line ) )input.append( line );
      cout<<input<<endl;
 }


Input : 

            I am Vooo OOOO
            I am vooo oooOOO oooo
                       oOOOOOoooOOOO

Output: 

            I am Vooo OOOOI am vooo oooOOO oooo           oOOOOOoooOOOO
```

Is there any mistake ?

Comment: *"not showing the result in the way it is supposed to when I print it"* can you elaborate? perhaps show what output you're getting vs what you're wanting?

Comment: @kmdreko I mean, The input and output don't look similar when I print the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake. You are not appending a new line every time while taking a line from the user.

See...

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input,line;
    while(getline(cin,line))input.append(line+"\n");
    input[input.size()-1]='\0';
    cout<<input<<endl;

}
```

Comment: It worked. But why input[input.size()-1]='\0'; this line ?

Comment: That line just replace the last unexpected newline character by a null character. Because every string must have a null character at the end.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks for your help.